# How to set focus on first field of input in BootStrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the focus to the first input element in an HTML form independent from the id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277544/how-to-set-the-focus-to-the-first-input-element-in-an-html-form-independent-from)

I'm using BootStrap with ASP.NET MVC4. There is one login form but I'm unable to set focus on first input field.

How to set focus on first field of input? Is there any BootStrap class that uses to set focus?

Comment: @Richard : BootStrap is missing in duplication question that you have mentioned.

Comment: This question is not specific to bootstrap.  The solution is the same whether you're using bootstrap or not.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There isn't a Bootstrap-specific class or function that does this*, but HTML5 provides [the `autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute) for input fields.

[This attribute currently enjoys wide browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus).

*-Since you are using Bootsrap, and Bootstrap is powered by jQuery, you could "shim" older browsers that otherwise don't support autofocus:

```
$('[autofocus]:first').focus();
```

Comment: Hmm, my answer is pretty much a duplicate of the answers to the Q/A @Richard references. Original content: fail.

Comment: Though the consensus is nice reinforcement.

Comment: Tip: If you have Modernizr you can check if this shim is needed with `Modernizr.input.autofocus` (