# I need to create a reset button that sets focus on the first form field after the form resets

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML5 Code:

```
<form name="memberInfo">
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Username</td><td><input id="username"   /></td></tr>
<button type = "reset" id = "resetButton">Reset</button>
<input type=button value="submit" onclick="Validate()"/>
</table>
</form>
```

and here is the JavaScript code:

```
window.onload =function(){
var _getForm = document.getElementById("memberInfo");
_getForm.addEventListener('reset',function(){
document.getElementById("username").focus()
})
}
```

Comment: How may forms do you have in your page?Please show your HTML code

Comment: have you tried .focus()?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277544/how-to-set-the-focus-to-the-first-input-element-in-an-html-form-independent-from

Comment: It's just one form

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id = "myForm">
<input type = "text" id ="text1">
<input type = "text" id ="text2">
<input type = "text" id ="text3">
<button type = "reset" id = "restButton">Reset</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#myForm").submit(function()
{
$('#myForm').trigger("reset");
$('#text1').focus();
return true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `button type ="reset"` and `focus()`

Hope this snippet will be useful

HTML

```
<form id = "myForm">
    <input type = "text" id ="text1">
    <input type = "text" id ="text2">
    <input type = "text" id ="text3">
    <button type = "reset" id = "restButton">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

JS

```
   var _getForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    _getForm.addEventListener('reset',function(){
    document.getElementById("text1").focus()
    })
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/zte055p9/1/)

**EDIT**

You can use `firstElementChild` instead of using `document.getElementById("firtChild")`.

Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/zte055p9/3/)

**Edit-2**

If you have put your code inside head tag, you can use window.onload to attach eventlistener after window has loaded

```
 window.onload =function(){
    var _getForm = document.getElementById("your form id");
    _getForm.addEventListener('reset',function(){
    document.getElementById("text1").focus()
    })
    }
```

**EDIT-3**

With latest changes in original questions here are few updates

Note

1. There is no form with `id=memberInfovar`. There is form with `name="memberInfovar"`.So this `_getForm = document.getElementById("memberInfo");` will throw`addEventListener of null`
2. `<input id="username"   />` add type of this input, that is `input type = "text"`
3. `<input type=button`. The `type` must be wrapped inside double quotes, that is `<input type="button">`

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/8q21nu4f/)

Comment: a downvote does not help unless it helps in correcting a answer.By the way the jsfiddle is working fine

Comment: I didnt down vote, yes it works in js fiddle but for some reason when i implement it in my code i get an error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Does your form has id as myForm? Also you you need to fire this after your dom has loaded

Comment: no its a different id but i changed the id in the javascript you gave me to match it.